# How to access a user's folder on Active Directory with his username and password?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a system where there are some users registered as Active Directory users. And they have some of their folders redirected to a directory in our server.

In my test environment there are 2 users `User1` and `User2` and they have their `Documents` folders redirected to my server.

- `User1`'s folder resides under `\\netapp\profiles\User1\Documents`
- `User2`'s folder resides under `\\netapp\profiles\User2\Documents`

And below is the server structure my admin provided me.

- dc.*myDomain* -> `DNS, DHCP, AD`
- Drive.*myDomain* -> the server my web application will run on
- W8User1.*myDomain* -> User1
- W8User2.*myDomain* -> User2

What I am trying to do is to provide them the ability to see their files from a web application that I will develop. I am pretty new to this Active Directory stuff and not even sure if it is even possible or not. Here is what I have so far.

```
using ( var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "<myDomain>", "DriveAdmin@<myDomain>", "password") ) 
{
    //Username and password for authentication.
    if ( context.ValidateCredentials("User1@<myDomain>", "password") )
    {
        var de = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://<myDomain>", "User1@<myDomain>", "password");

        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);

        var r1 = "";

        foreach ( SearchResult s in searcher.FindAll() )
            r1 += s.Path + "<br>";

        var r2 = "";

        foreach ( var d in Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\netapp\profiles\User1") )
            r2 += d + "<br>";

    }
    else /// unauthorized;
}
```

The validation works fine.

`r1` gives me a lot of records that I don't have a use of and don't understand eg.

> LDAP://bilgiturk.depo/..blah blah DC.. blah blah OU.. and so

And I can't even get `r2` as you would guess it gives `Access Denied` exception.

Is is doable? When I seach for Active Directory C# things on net I only come across with Active Direcrory administration operations like add user create group and things like that. So I started to get the feeling that it is not even possible? Please guide me.

Comment: :/ So it means am I dreaming here? Aren't there any workarounds?

Comment: By the way the design is that user will type in his username and password on my web application, then with that information I will do these works? Still impossible?

Comment: OK, if you get the user's name and password from him, you should be  able to *impersonate* that user, connect to his or her home directory, and enumerate the files under the context of his (her) own credentials. That should work - search for "impersonation in asp.net" or [see this blog post by Rick Strahl](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2005/Feb/24/Using-programmatic-Impersonation-from-an-ASPNET-Page)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking about both options but wasn't sure if they are viable or not. Now at least I know where should I head ;) thanks again.

Comment: @marc_s is right. Having access to active directory only makes sense for figuring out where these directories are, if that data is there. Otherwise accessing files would require the 'process' running as that user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read out the user's name, and his home directory, from Active Directory - but you **CANNOT** read the user's password, so you cannot impersonate that user to get access to his home directory.

You do have two options, however:

1. if you get the user's credentials (user name and password) from him directly, you can **impersonate** that user, and under that user's context, you should be able to get a listing of all the files and folders in his own home directory (see [Rick Strahl's blog post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2005/Feb/24/Using-programmatic-Impersonation-from-an-ASPNET-Page) for one way to do it)
2. if you can run the web application under a specific account that has (read-only, read directory) access to all the user's home folders, you could even avoid having to do impersonation (but in that case, your ASP.NET app's account needs extended access privileges)

Comment: I liked the first approach better, I will give it a try, and certainly accept this as the answer.

Comment: On the link you suggested in `LogonUser`  method there is a parameter `logonType` by changing that from `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` to `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` I have achieved what I want to do. Thanks again.